# Carrier density and size of Fermi surface

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy, charge-carrier

I think I've heard that a large Fermi surface implies a large carrier concentration and a small Fermi surface implies a small carrier concentration.

I am not really sure what the relationship is between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Luttinger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luttinger%27s_theorem) that relates the volume enclosed by the Fermi surface to the particle density.